вопрос по aiogram python
допустим я хочу запросить число через input но я не знаю как это реализовать в aiogram, "Введите первое число: " чел вводит 1, потом "Введите второе число: " чел вводит 99 и дальше отправляется рандом. ну это само собой, вот я и придумал себе рандомайзер но уже 3-4 день не могу понять как его сделать, мне говорят я тупой –
самое главное для меня это понять как запросить инпут что б он сохранился в переменную допустим в питоне num1 = input("Введите первое число: ") и в этот num1 сохраняется только то что в него ввели и дальше я могу с этим работать но в aiogram как я могу это сделать?
num1 = None num2 = None res = None
message.answer("Введите первое число: ")global num1 global num2 global res num1 = message.answer message.answer("Введите второе число:") num2 = message.answer("Введите второе:" )  только я не могу понять как код должен понять что это именно как инпут res = random randint(num1, num2)

Возможный дубликат вопроса: не могу разобраться с aiogram

для чего вы создаете новый топик, если недавно уже задавали вопрос с таким же подтекстом? вы читали, что вам отвечали там?

ну с похожим контекстом, мне ответили, но я конкретно задал вопрос по инпуту

@kassadinone непосредственно сам input там е используется, насколько я знаю. В общем виде, это выглядит так: пользователь отправляет команду боту, допустим /start, ТГ ее обрабатывает и отправляет боту апдейт, который содержит данные в формате json. Aiogram же переводит этот json в объекты питон. Отправленный текст, в данном случае /start, содержится в message.text - это и будет ваш input. Это грубое конечно описание

@kassadinone комментарий под своим прошлым вопросом посмотрите, я там давал ссылку на FSM, читайте и изучайте

а сорри не заметил коммент, спасибо попробую почитать

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то нужно использовать машину состояний — FSM (finite-state machine).
Импортируется все из aiogram.fsm.
